# Tweaking jQuery search for table

Tags: jquery, search, html-table

I have a search function for a table, I want to tweak it to only find matches in the Title column. And hide all items that don't match the title text. My code

> JS

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

> HTML

```
         <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Handlingar</th>
                    <th>Title</th>  <-----This column----
                    <th>Pris i kr</th>
                    <th>Skapad</th>
                    <th>Kategori</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (BuyAndSellAppWeb.Models.Advertisment objProduct in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @if (objProduct.SellerToken)
                        {
                            <td>

                                @Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit", new { id = objProduct.ID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Radera", "DeleteItem", new { id = objProduct.ID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Detaljer", "Details", new { id = objProduct.ID })

                        </td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Detaljer", "Details", new { id = objProduct.ID })
                            </td>
                        }
                        <td>@objProduct.ProductTitle</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.Price kr</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.Created.ToString("yyyy/MMM/dd")</td>
                        <td id="category">@objProduct.Category</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Tried a lot of different combinations that didn't do the trick.

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: yes, but it searches on all coulmns. I want to narrow it down to only find matches from the title coulm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out in your js . Hope it works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
      $('#search').keyup(function () {
          var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

          $rows.show().filter(function () {
              var text = $($(this).find('td')[1]).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
              return !~text.indexOf(val);
          }).hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: i have jusy modified `var text = $($(this).find('td')[1]).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();` line

Comment: Just solved it myself like this: `var text = $(this).children(":eq(" + "1" + ")").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();` Witch one do you think is better?

Comment: and thans by the way

Comment: both are fine in this case as there are only 5 <td> to search. you can use any as you wish :)

Comment: *"try this"* doesn't explain what is different or why it helps